# Can I present google analytics data to users within my application?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm creating an auction site and would like to provide my sellers with analytics related to their product pages - visitors, search terms, etc. I could roll my own analytics but want to know if it is possible (or forbidden) to use google analytics within my application and present that data to my users. Is this possible, has anyone done this and, if so, how did you go about it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do this.

The easiest method is to give your sellers direct access to GA.  I have no idea how you have your GA interface setup but you can setup profiles in lots of different ways (filters, segments, etc..) to have the profile show data only for the specific seller, and give their GA account access only to their profile.

Alternatively, GA provides an [API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/) for retrieving data from them and displaying on your own site.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can provides Real time data reporting via Google's Real Time API - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/devguide

Which will provide several data in the manner of [dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/)